# AlloyUI - difference between node.attr("id") and node.getAttribute("id")

Tags: liferay, alloy-ui

In AUI, what is the difference between

```
node.attr("id")
```

and

```
node.getAttribute("id")
```

where node is an object of type Node.

The documentation on getAttribute says "Allows getting attributes on DOM nodes, normalizing in some cases." but I don't understand what normalizing means, and in what case it is applied.

Thanks,
Alain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`node.attr` could be both getter and setter.

If you pass second argument to attr, it will be set as value of the attribute (the first argument).

`node.getAttribute` is only getter.

`node.getAttribute` normalizes the value for IE and especially for IE < 8. Without falling in many details, this means you may pass w3c standard attribute and it will work on all browsers.

Hope that helps!